# What is the meaning of "do | |" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

While reading some Ruby code I saw this:

```
create_table :talks do |t|
```

What is this notation `|variable|`? What does that do?

And also, where do I find help for these specific subjects like `| |`, `#{}`, and so on?

Comment: It's so hard to figure out which of the many questions about Ruby block syntax might best be considered a duplicate, I'll just suggest this search term instead: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+blocks

Comment: "where do i find help for these specific subjects...". Those are very basic, core-to-Ruby things so, at a minimum, read through the online version of ["Programming Ruby"](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/). It's a bit out of date, but those basics still apply.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a way of defining arguments for a block, in a similar way to `def methodname(arg1, arg2)`

A nice explanation of blocks is available [from Robert Sosinski](http://web.archive.org/web/20160922220431/http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas)

Comment: https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/  This article has a better explanation.

Answer (score 22):

You may also hear them referred to as goal posts. They are essentially named arguments that one can use to iterate over the data within a collection. For example, with an array:

```
# Print 1 2 3 4
[1,2,3,4].each do |e|
    print "#{e} "
end
```

Or with a key, value map, you would have multiple arguments between the goal posts

```
m = {"ruby" => "rails", "groovy" => "grails", "scala" => "lift", "java" => "spring"}
m.each do |lang, framework|
    # print the keys first - "ruby groovy scala java"
    print "#{lang} "
    # print the values second - "rails grails lift spring" 
    print "#{framework} "
end
```

Your question sounds more specific to the Ruby language than Ruby on Rails. I would check out some of these links:

- [About Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/about/)
- [Ruby in 20 Minutes](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/)

Comment: 1. No one calls them 'goal posts'.  2. They are not named arguments 3. You are not 'iterating over them'

Comment: 1. debatable; 2. Splitting hairs on words; the Ruby documentation refers to them as parameters, not named arguments; 3. Perhaps 'iterating' is not 100% correct, but the premise remains the same - the code block is called for each element in the collection.

Comment: 1. https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/ruby-arrays "goalposts" (c.2006).